# How to spy this code

Tags: qunit, sinon

I have below code in one of my controller classes:

```
initialize:function(){
    var myView = new MyViewClass({ vent : this.getParent().getVent(); });
    ..... other code of the initialize method
},
getParent(){
    .... returns the parent of this class
}
```

Now the `getParent()` method returns the parent of this class and the `getVent()` method of the parent returns parents' vent. How do I use spy so that I can run the `initialize` method to test it.

Comment: Could you show where the parent comes from originally.

Comment: The parent is a marionette layout and the controller written above renders a view inside that layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this solved. First I saw actually which parent controller was getting called by the `getParent()` method, stubbed the `getVent()` of parent controller and then stubbed `getParent()` method of this controller to return an object of the parent controller